# Error in creating project with Citrus Admin UI

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I'm trying to create a project using Citrus Admin UI but I get the following error message:

> Error! Failed to create new project.
>
> What happened!?
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.consol.citrus.admin.exception.ApplicationRuntimeException: Failed to create project from Maven archetype

I have followed these steps for installing and creating a new project:

1. Downloaded war executable with curl.
2. Runned `java -jar citrus-admin.war` command.
3. Opened `http://localhost:8080` with Google Chrome.
4. Created new project with the following parameters:

   ```
   Maven Archetype
   GroupId: com.consol.citrus.mvn
   ArtifactId: citrus-quickstart
   Version: 2.7.2
   Project
   GroupId: io.mpac.citrus-sample
   ArtifactId: citrus-sample
   Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
   Package: io.mpac.citrus
   ```

I tried with **Java SE 1.8.0_151**

Comment: Do you have Maven installed on your host? This is a prerequisite

Comment: @ChristophDeppisch Yep, in fact command `mvn -v` returns `Apache Maven 3.5.3 ...`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a bug in citrus-admin 1.0.2! The admin UI was using the old Maven groupId of the archetype `com.consol.citrus.mvn`. The new groupId should be `com.consol.citrus.archetypes`

Issue has already been fixed and released with v1.0.3.